# How to print execution stack of threads while they are consuming lots of CPU?

Tags: multithreading, cpu, windbg, diagnostics

Does anybody know how to achive the following task.

Application sometimes eats lots of CPU, ProcessExplorer (procexp.exe) shows periodical high kernel CPU load (~60-80). I see in procexp that some threads do something that consumes lots of kernel time. In that moment I would like to print execution stack of those busy threads.

Is there any monitoring tool that can show that kind of information or some WinDbg script, etc?

Comment: I've just posted answer under assumption that this is about java processes. Is that right, if not I'll remove it.

Comment: No, it is .net/native process on windows. Sorry, I did not mention it before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest using [ProcDump](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/dd996900).

A command like:

> procdump -c 60 -s 3 -ma -n 5 -x Your.exe your.dmp

Which will take a full memory dump when the process exceeds 60% CPU utilization for 3 consecutive seconds and do that up to 5 times.  This way you can compare the different dumps and see where the process is spending its time.

Answer (score 1):

One opportunity is to use the ProcDump from sysinternals to take dumps when 
CPU load exceed a limit you specify. 
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/dd996900
Or you can look in the windbg help for “Tracking Down a Processor Hog”